# Why and how are we creating instance of class within the same class?

Tags: java

I have two questions please help

```
public abstract class ListItem {
    protected ListItem rightLink = null;
    protected ListItem leftLink = null;
}
```

Before we used to define data type as char, int, String but now why we are creating data type as the class name?
is this instance of the class within the same class why are we using it what will it store?

The second question is

```
protected Object value;
```

what kind of object is this?

Comment: There are no instances created by this code; these fields will hold `null`, which is not a reference to an instance. The `protected Object value;` field will also initially hold `null`, even though there isn't an `= null` initializer, because `null` is the default value for a field of reference type.

Answer (score 2):

That class is an object in a linked list, that is to say an object that is part of a chain of similar items, with a 'left' and 'right' link. So the leftLink points to a similar object to the 'left' and the rightLink points to a similar object to the right. Because the class is abstract, we can't create a ListItem object, we need to derive from it first, which makes sense, since otherwise we would have no data in each item, but just links!

What seems to be confusing you is the use of the class name ListItem inside the class definition. But what this means in this case is simply that the ListItem has fields which may reference other objects of the same type as itself.